# Get() returning None despite use of default parameter

Tags: python-3.x

I'm just trying to troubleshoot a homework problem. We're supposed to create a function that takes up to four parameters: a string (message), a boolean (is it a float?), an operation command (add, subtract, etc), and two numbers.

The function should spit out the result based on the operation and numbers provided.

E.g.:

calculate(message="The answer is ", operation="subtract", make_float=False, first=18, second=8)

Should return: "The answer is 10."

The solution uses the the .get() method a lot. There are default arguments outlined, but I keep getting None when I call the function.

Any help is appreciated

I tried googling to see if any other students ran into the same issue.
Tried checking all of the get() instances to make sure I wasn't missing any default values or commas.

'''

```
def calculate(**kwargs):
    operation_dict = {
        'add': kwargs.get('first',0) + kwargs.get('second',0), 
        'subtract': kwargs.get('first',0) - kwargs.get('second',0),
        'divide': kwargs.get('first',0) / kwargs.get('second',0),
        'multiply': kwargs.get('first',0) * kwargs.get('second',0)
    }
    float_or_no = kwargs.get('make_float', False)

    operation_input = operation_dict[kwargs.get('operation','add')] 
    if float_or_no == True:
        final = "{} {}".format(kwargs.get('message','The result is '), 
        float(operation_input))
    else:
        final = "{} {}".format(kwargs.get('message', 'The result is '), 
        int(operation_input))
```

'''

I just keep getting None.

Comment: You're not returning anything; do `return final` after the `else` branch.

Comment: Ahhhh, thank you so much